# Retrieving MySQL stored procs OUT parameters in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a question regarding what is the best approach to using stored procs in mysql with hibernate. I am running mysql version **5.7.14** with hibernate **4.0.0.Final** as my ORM tool. Now in mysql database, I have a stored proc defined below:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS LK_spInsertBaseUser;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `LK_spInsertBaseUser`(f_name  VARCHAR(255),
                                       l_name  VARCHAR(255),
                                       n_name  VARCHAR(255),
                                       pwd     VARCHAR(255),
  OUT                                  user_id INT)
  BEGIN
    ## Declaring exit handler
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
      @state = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
      @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO,
      @message = MESSAGE_TEXT;
      SET @full_error = CONCAT('ERROR ', @errno, ' (', @state, '): ', @message);
      SELECT @full_error;
      ROLLBACK;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT first_name
                  FROM base_user
                  WHERE first_name = f_name AND last_name = l_name AND nick_name = n_name)
    THEN
      INSERT INTO base_user (first_name, last_name, nick_name, password)
      VALUES (f_name, l_name, n_name, pwd);
      SET user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
      SELECT @user_id AS userId;
    ELSE
      SET @exiting_user = CONCAT('Base user already exists');
      SELECT @exiting_user;
      ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

As we can see from my proc above, if the insert works, the id of the new record is stored in the OUT parameter **user_id** and we do a select as well. However, if there is a error I print out the error. Now, here is the heart of the question. I ran into a few hiccups when trying to execute the stored proc via hibernate. I finally came up with a solution but I am not convinced it is the right solution. Let me go through the various attempts i went through.

*Attempt 1*:
I decided to use ***@NamedNativeQueries*** annotation for my BaseUser Entity (note: base_user sql table maps to BaseUser pojo entity). Below is the code snippet:

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="insertUserResult", columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "userId")})
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = "spInsertBaseUser",
                query = "CALL LK_spInsertBaseUser(:firstName, :lastName, :nickName, :password, @user_id)",
                resultSetMapping = "insertUserResult"
        )
})
```

Now, in the Dao class I created a method to invoke the named query via the session object like so:

```java
Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("spInsertBaseUser")
        .setParameter("firstName", user.getFirstName())
        .setParameter("lastName", user.getLastName())
        .setParameter("nickName", user.getNickName())
        .setParameter("password", user.getEncodedPassword());
Object data = query.list();
System.out.println(data);
```

Now this works partially. It inserts the data into the database however the data object is null. It seems the out parameter isn't set or even retrieved.  I then decided to use a different approached and use the CallableStatement object. Below is the code:

*Attempt 2:*

```
getSession().doWork((Connection connection) -> {
    CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{call LK_spInsertBaseUser(?, ? , ?, ?, ?)}");
    statement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
    statement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
    statement.setString(3, user.getNickName());
    statement.setString(4, user.getEncodedPassword());
    statement.registerOutParameter(5, Types.INTEGER);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(statement.getInt(5));
});
```

This works and it is fairly quick however, I have read that the instantiation of the prepareCall is expensive so I guess the real question is, is this solution the acceptable standard or should I continue to figure out the NamedNativeQuery approach in the quest for ***better performance***?

Comment: @Drew this is not a duplicate. In fact it is very different from the questions that have been asked. This will also help others really understand things since there isn't really a clear cut way of handling this.

Comment: How about the part that you have no chance of sending back output with your parameters as all `IN` vars?

Comment: I will handle that case later and currently not worrying about it at this time. However, I will say one thing. Using the CallableStatement approach. If a error occurs, I simply get 0 back.